# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method on channel )

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I am trying to call a method from a kotlin class on a android module from a dart class, however, I keep receiving the

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method on channel)

couldnt find anything wrong with it

dart code:

```
class ****{
  MethodChannel _methodChannel = MethodChannel('android3ds/channel');

  customizar() async {
    try {
      await _methodChannel.invokeMethod('customizar');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

kotlin code

```
class *****(var activity: Activity, val environment: Environment) {

    lateinit var flutterEngine : FlutterEngine


    val CHANNEL = "android3ds/channel"

    val methodChannel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).
    setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
        if (call.equals("customizar")) {
            customizar()
        }
    }
fun customizar() {
}
```

Comment: Your code looks okay, at least from what you've shared.
Have you tried reloading <flutter run> your app, don't hot reload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Called the kotlin class from the MainActivity.kt and it worked:

```
internal class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)

        var kotlin_class: **** = ****(this, Environment.SANDBOX)

        provideFlutterEngine(this)?.let { GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(it) }

        val CHANNEL = "android3ds/name"

        val methodChannel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine?.dartExecutor?.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).
        setMethodCallHandler{ call, result ->
            if (call.method.equals("customizar")){
                kotlin_class.customizar()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Still getting the same issue.